# HTML5 for hybrid mobile app

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app

i am new to hybrid mobile app. I have some experience in website development using html5, css, javascript.

I wish to ask, if i wish to create a hybrid mobile app, do my code need to be mobile responsive first so that it will display correctly like a mobile responsive site on mobile phone?

Hope someone can help to advice me on this.

Example, if i create a website that have a login form that are not mobile responsive, if i use that code to create my hybrid mobile app, will it work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a RWD web page is recommended, because your app could be runs on Tablet.

And also, you should test your page on In-App Browser.

Log-in, session, etc. are controlled by web server, there is nothing about your app in this part.

Comment: Hi, RRTW, thanks for your reply. For the log-in, session, i am not too concern on them as i will be focusing on the UI while another of my friend will be on the backend stuff. 

When you mentioned RWD web page is recommended, so it is okay even if it is not responsive?

And if i utilise Mobile UI Framework like Ionic etc, can i say that my code does not need to follow RWD as i saw some of their tutorial online, they did not adopt RWD concept in their development but the output are showing like a native app on browser and mobile.

Comment: As my experience, RWD will be the best option, but if your page was only for your app and will not running on PC / Tablet(landscape mode) browser, then RWD isn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks alot for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to create hybrid mobile apps better use any frameworks. Checkout [ionicFramework](https://ionicframework.com/)

Ionic provides RWD components that you can quickly use in your project. And provides plugins that you can use to achieve native functionalites in your hybrid mobile app.

checkout cordova website also.